# To malloc a huge array in C

Tags: c, arrays, segmentation-fault, malloc

I have an array `int Array[17000][10][6][6]`

But I got segmentation fault when I declare it.

So far I have been just using small arrays, I know that I have to use malloc, but I don't know how and I've been having a had time trying to understand the tutorials that I found.

Thanks for your help in advance

Tamalero

Comment: STACK OVERFLOW!!

Comment: I did something wrong?

Comment: The huge multidimensional-array is in all likelyhood too big to fit on the stack, thus overflowing it. haccks is making a reference to the name of the website and your problem.

Comment: In any case, I don't know if I should just give you the code to `malloc` this. If you don't know how `malloc` works just giving the code isn't going to do you much good and you should really get to know it as it's one of the most important functions of the C standard-library. My tip is to just play around with it a bit (with some smaller numbers) and perhaps re-read those tutorials.

Comment: You are right kninnug, but at least I want to know if I'm right thinking that the segmentation fault is caused by this. Let me close the question after knowing that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like in [Tamalero's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20683909/28169), but as you might glean it can become a bit unwieldy.

The alternative is to do the indexing manually, i.e. allocate a compact array of just the data (the integers), no pointer arrays.

Then do the indexing by applying the required expression to compute the offset from the start of the array to the desired element:

```
const size_t ws = 17000, xs = 10, ys = 6, zs = 6;
int *array = malloc(ws * xs * ys * zs * sizeof *array);

array[w * (xs * yz * zs) + x * (ys * zs) + y * zs + z] = 4711;
```

You can wrap the indexing into a macro of course to make it easier to repeat.

This will use less memory, is much easier to set up, and quite possibly faster since it does (way) fewer memory accesses per actual access, i.e. 1 instead of one per dimension due to the pointer-chasing.

Answer (score 1):

Even simpler than either of the existing two answers (only appropriate when the dimensions are static, of course):

```
int (*array)[10][6][6] = malloc(17000 * sizeof(*array));

array[w][x][y][z] = 4711;   // ... "natural" indexing ...

free(array);
```

Plus, the type of `array` is *almost* the same as in the OP's original code.

Answer (score 0):

```
int w=17000, x = 10, y = 6, z = 6;          
int ****array;
int i, j, k, l, m;
array = malloc(sizeof(int ***) * w);   /* size of an integer times the i length */
for(i = 0; i < w; ++i)
{   array[i] = malloc(sizeof(int **) * x);

    for(j = 0; j < x; ++j)
    {   array[i][j] = malloc(sizeof(int *) * y);

        for(k = 0; k < y; ++k)
        {   array[i][j][k] = malloc(sizeof(int) * z);
        }
    }
}

/* Check array */
m=0;
for (i = 0; i < w; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < x; j++) {
        for (k = 0; k < y; k++) {
            for (l = 0; l < z; l++) {
                array[i][j][k][l] = m++;
            }
        }
    }
}
  m=0;
for (i = 0; i < w; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < x; j++) {
        for (k = 0; k < y; k++) {
            for (l = 0; l < z; l++) {
                array[i][j][k][l] = m;
            }
        }
    }
}
/* free memory used to making the array */

 for (i = 0; i < w; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < x; j++) {
        for (k = 0; k < y; k++) {
            free(array[i][j][k]);
            array[i][j][k] = NULL;
        }
        free(array[i][j]);
        array[i][j] = NULL;
    }
    free(array[i]);
    array[i] = NULL;
}
free(array);
array = NULL;

printf("Array prepare done\n");
```

Comment: Every time I see another for, my head goes OUCH, so I guess unwind answer should be better. But this has more visibility. Or it seems so...

Comment: LOL you are right, It's important to add that this solution is for dynamic sizes of the array.